# Migrating an 1.5 Angularjs + bower built with Grunt to ES6?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6

I realize this won't be a trivial task, but there seems to be a few parts regarding this.

- Convert bower packages to NPM (could try boweraway?)
- Remove bower package imports in the root index html
- Update all javascript to do explicit exports and imports (files + node modules) rather than rely on global namespace
- Probably have to update Gruntfile or migrate to webpack? What is preferred?

I have a general awareness of these steps, but it seems to be a daunting task, especially for a codebase with few hundreds of angularjs objects (controllers, directives, services, etc) across a couple hundred files.

Does anyone have any tips / experience regarding this ? Do my steps seem reasonable, or is there another path of less resistance?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Try not to target ES6. Instead target the browsers of your users and use what they can use. ES2021 (ES12) was recently released and is mostly implemented in modern browsers.

Comment: @evolutionxbox that's fine too, just more looking for steps in getting away from ES5 haha.

Comment: ES5 is completely contained inside ES6 & ES2021. What are you trying to move away from?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm not trying to move away from anything, but rather improve the codebase with es6+ features that we could use. E.g. explicit imports/exports, const/let, "for(const x of xs)" syntax, arrow functions, destructuring, template strings, among bunch of other things. ES6+ provides a great dev experience, in other words.

Comment: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/ bower have a document which describes how to move to another bundler.